# Disable Facebook mobile browser detection?

Tags: facebook, mobile, query-string, browser-detection

Does anyone know of a way to disable the mobile browser detection and redirect feature of Facebook via querystring parameters?

For example, if I go to [www.facebook.com/CraigslistGenie](http://www.facebook.com/CraigslistGenie) in a mobile browser, I get redirected to http://m.facebook.com/CraigslistGenie.  I would like the user to stay on the www version of the page.

Comment: In your browser object (WebView or whatever), you need to change the user agent string to be a desktop browser one. I don't think there's any GET params to skip the mobile redirect.

Answer (score 20):

you either change the user-agent to achieve that or you add `?m2w` to the link i.e.   http://www.facebook.com/CraigslistGenie/?m2w does NOT redirect (tested on Android) while http://www.facebook.com/CraigslistGenie does redirect to http://m.facebook.com/CraigslistGenie

For reference see [here](http://forums.mozillazine.org/viewtopic.php?f=40&t=1587815&start=15) and [here](http://rightyaleft.com/tricks/how-to-access-pc-version-of-facebook-in-mobile/).

Comment: +1, completely correct. Modifying your user agent is, [with thin exception](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metasploit_Project), your key to equal citizen status with any browser. Do note that this doesn't work where browser capabilities differ, but for reasons of grabbing the full version of the site, this should do just fine.

Answer (score 1):

The first answer is correct, however if you want it to work on an Android phone (and keep working when you click on links within the site) you need to go into the browser settings (after you've gone to the http://facebook.com?m2w) and check the "Desktop version" setting.
This will prevent the browser from constantly trying to send you to either the mobile version of the site or the FB app.

Answer (score 0):

Method given by Yahia is good. Adding ?m2w to link means converting mobile to web view.

Or,
Change settings of mobile browser i.e. User Agent. Both Steel and Dolphin browsers allow you to change that setting however. Both are free in the market. (I am not doing any marketing of browsers.)

Some of you may have noticed that, despite changing the User-Agent in the browser, you are still sent to a mobile website anyway. Check [this patches](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1284963) given.

Check [this huge discussion](http://talk.maemo.org/archive/index.php/t-53311.html) about tricks used for hiding mobile browser.