# How to prevent facebook 301 redirect when using window.open?

Tags: javascript, facebook

I am using the facebook business extension and have the following bit of code in my FBE integration::-

```
initFaeClient() {
    // Handling the case for closing all open FAE client as suggested in DOC
    if (this.clientWindow) { this.clientWindow.close() }

    this.clientWindow =
      window.open(this.fetchClientUrl(), this.clientWindowName, utill.setWindowOptions())
}
```

Basically `this.fetchClientUrl()` is going to return the following :

```
http://www.facebook.com/ads/dia?origin=http%3A%2F%2Fmytestsite.test
```

The problem is when this code runs from a mobile device and hits the above url , facebook does ( I believe ) a 301 redirect and then the url changes to:-

```
http://m.facebook.com/ads/dia?origin=http%3A%2F%2Fmyshopmatic.test
```

I don't wont this to happen , is there any way i can prevent facebooks 301 redirect ? the FBE api does't work with the `m.facebook.com` url and i've spoken to a facebook rep about this, so how do i prevent this redirect ? anything i can pass inside the `window.open` method ?

Comment: You could try if the method mentioned here still works, https://stackoverflow.com/a/10019373/10955263 - but that is very old. Don’t know if there’s any more current replacement.

Comment: @04FS , this solution no longer works unfortunatly :(

Comment: I don’t know if there is any current replacement for that parameter. If not, then there’s little you can do about this in the first place - Facebook decides when to redirect, probably based on stuff such as the User-Agent request header.

Comment: Why do you want to prevent a 301?

Comment: @WizKid because facebooks API does't work for `m.facebook.com`, in my instance `http://www.facebook.com/ads/dia?origin=http%3A%2F%2Fmytestsite.test` works , but `http://m.facebook.com/ads/dia?origin=http%3A%2F%2Fmytestsite.test` will not work.